# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /home/casselwa/public_html/oauth2/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/functions.php on line 41

Tags: oauth-2.0

I get following error after installing guzzle with composer and running it in oauth-2.0

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /home/casselwa/public_html/oauth2/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/functions.php on line 41

Answer (score 2):

I am also getting same error. With a quick google search i found out that this is an issue with PHP version. Current version of GuzzlePHP requires PHP 5.5. What PHP version you are using ?